# How to display minimum and maximum values for DateTimeAxis or LinearAxis in Silverlight Toolkit's line series

Tags: silverlight, charts, silverlight-toolkit, series

I'm hoping this is a simple question, though I have not been able to find an answer yet on the web.

I'm using the April 2010 release of Silverlight Toolkit's line series and I'm required to display only the minimum and maximum values (which I specify) in a DateTimeAxis or LinearAxis. By "display", I mean showing the actual "tick" plus its related value on both ends of the axis.

Is this possible at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.   Set your Minimum and Maximum values and set your Interval as the difference between Minimum and Maximum.

ie:

```
<toolkit:LinearAxis Minimum="0" Orientation="X" Maximum="105" Interval="105"/>
```

UPDATE: (for DateTimeAxis)

It is a little harder to fix the DateTimeAxis.  Here's my solution via IValueConverter:

```
 public class AxisFormatter : IValueConverter
  {
    public Object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()) != maxDate && DateTime.Parse(value.ToString() != minDate)
            return null;
        else
            return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

where minDate and maxDate are your hard-coded values for the upper and lower bounds of your axis.

Also, you will need to implement this Converter via the AxisLabelStyle of your axis.  Thus, in your Styles.xaml or wherever you store your styles, place this style:

```
<Style x:Key="DateTimeAxisLabelStyle1" TargetType="charting:DateTimeAxisLabel">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="YearsIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:yyyy}"/>
    <Setter Property="MonthsIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:d}"/>
    <Setter Property="WeeksIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:d}"/>
    <Setter Property="DaysIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:d}"/>
    <Setter Property="HoursIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:t}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinutesIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:t}"/>
    <Setter Property="SecondsIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:T}"/>
    <Setter Property="MillisecondsIntervalStringFormat" Value="{}{0:mm:ss.fff}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:DateTimeAxisLabel">
                <TextBlock DataContext="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource axisFormatter}}"></TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and add xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YOURPROJECTNAME to your XAML file as well as adding
    local:AxisFormatter x:Key="AxisFormatter" 
to your resource dictionary.

Then in your axis's actual XAML declaration, put it as shown below;

```
<toolkit:DateTimeAxis AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource DateTimeAxisLabelStyle1}"  Orientation="X" />
```

Sorry that this solution is kind of complicated, and let me know if you need further guidance.

Comment: Hey LDavis562, thanks for the quick response! Your solution does seem to work well for the LinearAxis, however I can't get it to work for a DateTimeAxis. I tried in code-behind to set the interval to "axisDateTime.Maximum.Value.Subtract(axisDateTime.Minimum.Value).TotalDays" (where the interval type was "Days"), without luck. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for noticing it doesn't work on DateTimeAxis, I'm going to update my answer (not sure if that is the right place for it) to address the DateTimeAxis.

Comment: I really do appreciate the time and effort you put in your answer, LDavies562. I followed your suggestion above, but that still doesn't work, and I think I can see why: none of the DateTime values generated for the axis matches the hardcoded min and max values, so I wind up with an axis with no values. I tried playing with the interval, to no avail. If it interests you, the min date I am working with is 4/12/2008 2:54:11 AM, and the max date is 3/11/2009 2:14:58 AM. With an interval setting of "auto", I get a 14-day interval in the axis, with none of the values matching my min and max dates.

Comment: Update: I sort of got the DateTimeAxis working by the setting IntervalType to "days" and the actual Interval to 1. The side effect is that the chart renders a bit slower (because it generates over 300 ticks for the axis) and the max date has a greater vertical offset (probably because Silverlight still renders all the dates "invisibly" and the max date is in the second row of numbers). Anyway, I'm still open to a more elegant solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just replied on your Q on my blog:http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.com/2011/02/silverlight-4-toolkit-zoom-and-pan.html?showComment=1311446800567#c5905503102900111342

"Hi Victor, I wouldn't think you could achieve this with the built in axis as it's not designed to do this. However you could potentially do this by styling out the x axis on the chart like I do in this example, then create your own pseudo axis by placing two textblocks underneath external to the chart at each end; it may take some time to get the formatting right but will definitely work as it's a simple work-around. You could use LINQ to get the min and max when the data is loaded and bind to these values."

Get the code which contains example of styling out axes here:

http://slchartzoomandpan.codeplex.com/